# Are "freelancer" and "free-agent" interchangeable?

Tags: word-meaning, difference

Are "freelancer" and "free-agent" interchangeable? I am stuck at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The terms are not interchangeable.

**Free agent** is a term used almost exclusively in professional sports, to refer to an athlete who is eligible to sign a contract with any team. Athletes often sign exclusive contacts for a term of several years; if the term of the contract expires or the contract is cancelled for some other reason, that athlete becomes a free agent and might sign a deal somewhere else. This usage is explained in more detail [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_agent_(disambiguation)).

A **freelancer** is somebody who is not an employee of a particular company but does individual jobs for various clients. This often happens in creative or technical fields like journalism or web development.